# How to conditionally set destructuring

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I wasn't sure the best way to title this post, feel free to retitle it as you wish.

I have a method which if it decides to bail, I have it returning null.  Otherwise it'll return a promise.

On the receiving side, how can I manage both scenarios?  For example I'm trying to figure out how to capture the case where it bails (I get null back from the call to deletePRBucket:

**Caller - My test**

```
it('can create a new S3 branch', async () => {
  const options = { branch: '11' }
   // first lets check if we delete it if it already exists before trying to re-create it
  let { error, stdout, stderr } = await Deploy.deletePRBucket(options.branch)

   ({ error, stdout, stderr } = await Deploy.createPRBucket(options)),
          result = JSON.parse(stdout)

          expect(result.Location).to.equal(`http://oursite-${options.branch}.s3.amazonaws.com/`)
})
```

So I get an error here that the values `error`, `stdout`, and `stderr` don't exist because my delete method returns a null if it doesn't attempt to delete (because the bucket doesn't exist). So not sure how to handle the case where it decides to bail and returns null instead of returning the promise.

**UPDATED** (also included the bucketExists implementation):

**Implementation**

```
export async function bucketExists(bucketName){
  console.log(`attempting to find bucket oursite-${bucketName}`)
  let exists = null
  try {
    let { error, stdout, stderr } = await exec(`aws s3api head-bucket --bucket oursite-${bucketName}`)
    exists = stdout === ""
  }
  catch(err){
    exists = false
  }

  return exists
}

export async function deletePRBucket(branch){
  const bucketExists = await this.bucketExists(branch)
  if(!bucketExists) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({ error, stdout, stderr })
    })
  }

  return exec(`aws s3 rb s3://oursite-${branch} --force`)
}
```

I mean I suppose I could just return an object { error, stdout, stderr } and check that stdout is null or something like that, maybe return a promise? `if(!bucketExists) return new Promise(() => { error, stdout, stderr })`

Comment: Why not always return a promise and resolve or reject it depending on if function bails out or not?

Comment: I went with the return a promise that resolves { error, stdout, stderr }

Comment: Cool. Good luck!

Comment: keep in mind exec() is already promisified

Comment: fyi see updated post, I included a bit more info

Comment: my head hurts right now

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a question of error handling:

```
export async function deletePRBucket(branch){
  const bucketExists = await this.bucketExists(branch)
  if(!bucketExists) throw new Error("bucket");

  return exec(`aws s3 rb s3://oursite-${branch} --force`)
}

...

try{
 let { error, stdout, stderr } = await Deploy.deletePRBucket(options.branch);
}catch(e){
  console.log("error");
}
```

Comment: well I don't want to throw errors, I'd console log it.  the caller should be able to check easily if it was created or not.  If the delete fails then it is logged

Comment: cool I see now what you did..but I really want to rely on them remember to try/catch.  I'd like to have it fail nicer for them..so lets say I want to run this delete right before a createBucket, and I call delete then I call create, well I don't want it to blow up if it can't delete a non-existent bucket, because if it does, then my createBucket won't be called.you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a default object to be used if the promise returns `null`.

```
let { error, stdout, stderr } = (await Deploy.deletePRBucket(options.branch)) || {};
```

Comment: that would require the call be be made BEFORE the {}.  If the bucket doesn't even exist, I don't even want to call the deletePRBucket...which is why I have the first check for existence of the bucket. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your code???

Comment: The check for the bucket is inside `deletePRBucket`, why do you also need to check if it exists before calling?